# IE7&8 issue with cloning elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having an issue with IE where I am cloning a block of form elements, according to a number selected in a dropdown list. If 3 is selected in the dropdown list, I want to repeat the block of questions and manipulate the name attribute so that they are unique to each block. This works fine in Chrome, FF etc, but not in IE7 and IE8.

EDIT, turns out it's specific to IE7 and IE8: [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynhya/)

Here is my code, is there something I am doing which IE is known to have an issue with? All that happens currently is that IE shows "null" instead of each block which should appear. Thanks for any help.

```
    // Dropdown select
    $('#quantity').live("change", function(){

        $('.questions_clonable:not(:first)').remove();

        // Get value of selection
        var num = $(this).val();

        var cloned_el = $('.questions_clonable').clone();   

        if (num > 1)
        {  
            for (var i = 1; i < num; i++)
            {
                // Assign cloned block to new var
                var new_block = cloned_el;  

                // Bit of a workaround needed to clone properly, reiterating class name
                $('.multiple_questions_container').append('<span class="questions_clonable hidden">'+new_block.html()+'</span>');

            }   
        }
    });
```

The form elements are wrapped in a span, as follows:

```
<span class="questions_clonable hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using cloned_el to get the html from, why not instead of doing

```
var cloned_el = $('.questions_clonable').clone();
```

and then

```
var new_block = cloned_el;
```

just to call new_block.html(), you do this:

```
var new_block_html = $('.questions_clonable').html();
```

then you can just reference new_block_html.

If you can post your markup as well it might help, as obviously if there are any ids this will cause some errors.

$.live() does not currently support the change event: 
Currently not supported: blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit [docs.jquery.com/Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

Could you perhaps try using livequery instead? [docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery)

EDIT - alternatively try using the .on() event rather than .live(), [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ynhya/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the response, this approach results in the "null" issue happening on all browsers. If I revert back to my original code in the OP, the issue only happens in IE. I'll get some more markup posted